# Split values separated by commas into variables in Python

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, trading, binance

I'm trying to get variables of a live trading order book using the 'python-binance' library.

```
depth = client.get_order_book(symbol='BTCUSDT')
print(depth)
```

This is the result.

```
'bids': [['34657.70000000', '0.57150000'], ['34655.76000000', '0.00035500'], ['34654.28000000', '0.01431800'][...]
'asks': [['34657.70000000', '0.57150000'], ['34655.76000000', '0.00035500'], ['34654.28000000', '0.01431800'][...]
```

The first value of each row is the price and the second one is the volume.

I would like to unify all 'price' values and 'volume' values into separate variables, so I would be able to sum all prices and all volumes separately.

Tried to find a related example using numpy or pandas but as you see, I'm such a newbie.

Thank you all

Comment: What is the `type(depth)`?

Comment: I created that variable unnecessarily and forgot to remove it...

Comment: thats not the point. what is the datatype of the printed thing you have shown in your answer? is it a `dict`?

Answer (score 0):

I predict you have those results in a dict.

```
price_vol = {}

for key in ['bids','asks']:
    for elem in depth[key]:
        price_vol[elem[0]] = elem[1]
```

That's it.

By the way, your exemple is wrong. You can't have same price for bids and ask positions at the same time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with a dictionary you can use `zip` and a list comprehension that flattens a nested list to get what you want -

```
d = client.get_order_book(symbol='EURUSD')

bp, bv, ap, av = [j for i in d.values() for j in list(zip(*i))]

print('bids price:', bp)
print('bids volume:', bv)
print('asks price:', ap)
print('asks volume:', av)
```

```
bids price: ('34657.70000000', '34655.76000000', '34654.28000000')
bids volume: ('0.57150000', '0.00035500', '0.01431800')
asks price: ('34657.70000000', '34655.76000000', '34654.28000000')
asks volume: ('0.57150000', '0.00035500', '0.01431800')
```

Comment: I'm not using any dictionary. Unfortunately I have no idea how to apply them for this, could you please provide an example? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: My friend, `depth = client.get_order_book(symbol='EURUSD')`, in this code `depth` is a variable. It stores the order book. Once you have run this, you use `print(depth)`. Instead of that can you type `print(type(depth))` and tell me what you get?

Comment: You are right, it is the dict. Sorry for that. As last question, how can the variable 'd' take the values directly from 'depth', instead of putting the values manually as you did here? d = {..}

Comment: updated my answer, it should work now. Yes exactly how you mention in your comment. Do mark the answer if it helped you to solve your question as it encourages me to help you in the future as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting this error :
TypeError: zip() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Comment: can you run `print(d.values()` and tell me what that returns?

Comment: I'm getting the error : SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Sure. This is the traceback : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dan\volume\orderbook.py", line 9, in <module>
    bp, bv, ap, av = [j for i in d.values() for j in list(zip(*i))]
  File "c:\Users\Dan\volume\orderbook.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    bp, bv, ap, av = [j for i in d.values() for j in list(zip(*i))]
TypeError: zip() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Comment: But this is `TypeError:`, you said you are getting `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF`